# List view not showing in panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

UPDATE:
I found if do this

```
this.add([topToolbar, {
        xtype: "fieldset",
        items: [showNameEditor, textEditor]
    },
    showsList, bottomToolbar
]);
```

and

```
layout: {
    type: 'fit'
}
```

Then the list shows but the textfields don't appear

Original:

I am trying to get a list to show in my panel the two textFields show but the list doesn't appear. I tried different Stores with the list but still it doesn't show.

```
var showNameEditor = {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
    required: true
};
var textEditor = {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
    required: true
};
var showsList = {
    xtype: 'list',
    title: 'Sample',
    itemTpl: '{title}',
    data: [{
            title: 'Item 1'
        }, {
            title: 'Item 2'
        }, {
            title: 'Item 3'
        }, {
            title: 'Item 4'
        }
    ]
};

this.add([topToolbar, {
        xtype: "fieldset",
        items: [showNameEditor, showsList, textEditor]
    },
    bottomToolbar
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify dimensions for `fieldset` & `form` if you want to display their contents so use `width` & `height` configs